# How to do multi-row calculations using awk on a large file

Tags: awk, summary

I have a big file that is sorted on the first word. I need to add a new column for each line with the proportional value:  line value/total value for that group; group is determined by the first column. In the below example, the total of group "a" = 100 and hence each line gets a proportion. The total of group "the" is 1000 and hence each line gets the proprotion value of the total of that group.

I need an awk script to do this.

**Sample File:**
a lot 10
a few 20
a great 20
a little 40
a good 10
the best 250
the dog 750 
zisty cool 20

**Output:**
a lot 10 0.1
a few 20 0.2
a great 20 0.1
a little 40 0.4
a good 10 0.1
the best 25 .25
the dog 75 .75
zisty cool 20 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe this as a "big file."  Consequently, this solution tries to save memory: it holds no more than one group in memory at a time.  When we are done with that group, we print it out before starting on the next group:

```
$ awk -v i=0 'NR==1{name=$1} $1==name{a[i]=$0;b[i++]=$3;tot+=$3+0;next} {for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],b[j]/tot} name=$1;a[0]=$0;tot=b[0]=$3;i=1} END{for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],b[j]/tot}}' file
a lot 10 0.1
a few 20 0.2
a great 20 0.2
a little 40 0.4
a good 10 0.1
the best 250 0.25
the dog 750 0.75
zisty cool 20 1
```

#### How it works

- `-v i=0`

  This initializes the variable `i` to zero.
- `NR==1{name=$1}`

  For the first line, set the variable `name` to the first field, `$1`.  This is the name of the group.
- `$1==name {a[i]=$0; b[i++]=$3; tot+=$3+0; next}`

  If the first field matches `name`, then save the whole line into array `a` and save the value of column (field) three into array `b`.  Increment the variable `tot` by the value of the third field.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],b[j]/tot} name=$1;a[0]=$0;tot=b[0]=$3;i=1`

  If we get to this line, then we are at the start of a new group.  Print out all the values for the old group and initialize the variables for the start of the next group.
- `END{for (j=0;j<i;j++){print a[j],b[j]/tot}}`

  After we get to the last line, print out what we have for the last group.

Comment: It works like a charm and very efficient too on a 100 million rows file.

Comment: Neither `-v i=0` nor `NR==1{name=$1}` are necessary here. The first is entirely unnecessary because variables are `""` or `0` by default. The second bit seems not to affect the output here but I'm less certain that it shouldn't.

Comment: @EtanReisner Maybe you are using a different `awk` than I am.  I found (GNU awk) that `-v i=0` is necessary because, unless the numeric context is otherwise made clear, `i` defaults to "", not 0.  As an alternative, I could have used `a[i+0]=$` but I believe that explicitly initializing `i` to zero is more clear/less obscure for people new to awk.

Comment: True, if you remove just `-v i=0` and leave the `NR==1` block it seems to go wrong and that is probably why. Without that pattern you don't hit a usage of `i` until after it has been assigned a value. But I still think the `NR==1` pattern is unnecessary (and possibly even wrong) you don't want to force the first line to be a complete group and print out.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$3; b[i++]=$0; c[j++]=$1; d[k++]=$3} END{for(i=0;i<NR;i++) {print b[i], d[i]/a[c[i]]}}' File
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat ff
a lot 10
a few 20
a great 20
a little 40
a good 10
the best 250
the dog 750
zisty cool 20
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ awk '{a[$1]+=$3; b[i++]=$0; c[j++]=$1; d[k++]=$3} END{for(i=0;i<NR;i++) {print b[i], d[i]/a[c[i]]}}' ff
a lot 10 0.1
a few 20 0.2
a great 20 0.2
a little 40 0.4
a good 10 0.1
the best 250 0.25
the dog 750 0.75
zisty cool 20 1
```

Logic: update an array (a[]) with first column as index for each line. save array b[] with complete line for each line, to be used in the end for printing. similarly, update arrays c[] and d[] with first and third column values for each line. at the end, use these arrays to get the results using a for loop, looping through all the lines processed. First printing the line as itself, then the proportion value.